# Употребление слова «мысочки» в стилизованном стихотворении

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, поэзия

Корректирую чужие стихи, как заметили, стилизованные под поэзию XIX века. Очень хочется заменить слово *мысочки*. Уместно ли оно вообще?

*На мысочках развернулась,

Снег подбросила, встряхнулась,

Засмеялась, улыбнулась —

Вот, что делает весна!*

Comment: Попробуйте предложить «на пуантах».

Comment: Дайте мне руку, нынче не просто//                
Ходить **на мысочках** по чистому воздуху//               
В метре от прокажённой земли.//                
Я обеспечу вам ваше парение //       
Тайными клятвами и уверениями,//            
Солнце и ветер в бокале сухого «Шабли»              

    П. Кашин "Барышня"

Answer (score 3):

Если предполагается, что *мысок* — это передняя часть ступни, то почему бы не быть и ласковому *мысочку*, особенно в стихах?
Мне кажется, что это вполне уместно.

*Я приподнялся [**на мыски**](https://mir-knigi.info/books/proza/klassicheskaya-proza/page-20-48655-kukushata-ili-zhalobnaya-pesn-dlya-uspokoeniya-serdca.html) и тронул Сандру за руку, что означало: «Не дрейфь! Мы едем! Все нормально!»* (А. И. Приставкин. Кукушата, или Жалобная песнь для успокоения сердца).

*Не успели поблагодарить судьбу за, слава богу, прошедшие минуты прогулки с вождями, как справа пересекает дорогу цепочка джигитов ― мальчики в черкесках, с кинжалами грациозно [**на мысочках**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=ZOeVDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT210&lpg=PT210&dq=%D1%81%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85&source=bl&ots=IokAqH4K2o&sig=ACfU3U34bfJymE98sLI7YWJoZJ-6-9QB0g&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwielMjDs_z7AhXqtYsKHfr2DfsQ6AF6BAgfEAM#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85&f=false) протанцевали мимо и скрылись в кустах* (Н. В. Мордюкова. Не плачь, казачка!).

И еще: я бы не стала ставить запятую после "вот".

Answer (score 0):

"На цыпочках"? Правда это тогда будет не в рифму. Мне кажется, что "на мысочках" вполне нормальное выражение, я бы не заменял.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение! "Мысок" - такое слово есть, конечно. Чаще оно о чулочно-носочном изделии. Я, конечно, автору не буду подсказывать. По-современному, мы говорим "на носочках" (например, из упражнений: "Встаньте на носочки!") Но здесь все "забубенено"))

Comment: Можно развернуться на носочках. В Нацкорпусе много таких примеров https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CqQBChXQvdCwINC90L7RgdC%2B0YfQutCw0YUiawppChwKB2NyZWF0ZWQiEQiAgICA%2BP%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEP%2F%2F%2F%2F8HCh0KCGJpcnRoZGF5IhEIgICAgPj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FBwoqCiRwcmlfY2F0OtGF0YPQtNC%2B0LbQtdGB0YLQstC10L3QvdCw0Y8aAggBKhcKCAgAEAoYMiAKIAAopIuflKXgtQpABTICCAE6AQEwAQ%3D%3D