# Приподняться — на ЧЁМ или на ЧТО?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Сомнения "образовались" при ответе на вопрос [о мысочках](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472790/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8).

*Я **[приподнялся на мыски](https://books.google.ee/books?id=wq_YCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=%D0%AF%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%20%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%83,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE:%20%C2%AB%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%84%D1%8C!%20%D0%9C%D1%8B%20%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC!%20%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE!%C2%BB&source=bl&ots=N4U2l8qwbL&sig=ACfU3U3Ss0F2kThKHfTEUNMA2WjnkD-GvQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU-bixzYP8AhVGmYsKHdDJBMgQ6AF6BAgHEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%AF%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%20%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%83%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%3A%20%C2%AB%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%84%D1%8C!%20%D0%9C%D1%8B%20%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC!%20%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE!%C2%BB&f=false)** и тронул Сандру за руку, что означало: «Не дрейфь! Мы едем! Все нормально!»* (А. И. Приставкин. Кукушата, или Жалобная песнь для успокоения сердца).

Посмотрела в толковом словаре:
[приподняться](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)
**1.** Немного подняться. *Нос лодки приподнялся. Брови приподнялись. Неуклюже приподняться. Приподняться на носках, на цыпочках. Быстро приподняться на локтях.*

Посмотрела в Нацкорпусе:
приподнялся на носках — 7, приподнялась на носках — 4;
приподнялся на носки — 9, приподнялась на носки — 8.

А как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **По-всякому правильно**: совпадение значений различных падежей — обычное дело в русском языке. Пространственные падежные значения обычно различаются, но потом на их основе развиваются предметные отношения. Тогда разница становится менее заметной и появляется свобода выбора.
2. **Семантику** условно можно объяснить так:  мы или встаем на что-то (на цыпочки, как на внешний предмет), или увеличиваем свой рост таким приемом.
3. **Примеры**

(1) Старыгин приподнялся **на цыпочки** и достал с одной из верхних полок большую картонную коробку.

Феликс приподнялся **на цыпочки** и, запустив руку через верх калитки, отщёлкнул задвижку, и мы вошли.

Не стал отпирать дверь в ее каморку, а приподнялся **на цыпочки** и заглянул в щель.

(2) Вовка нашел невысокий холмик, встал на него и приподнялся **на цыпочках**, заглядывая через заводской забор.

Костя помылся, установил на подоконнике карманное зеркальце и приподнялся **на цыпочках** ― посмотреть, каков он в нижней части.

Answer (score 0):

```
Я поднялся на ноги
```

Какой здесь член предложения **на ноги** ? Похоже, обстоятельство, или, если хотите, дополнение с функцией обстоятельства. Тогда не имеет значение какое управление в словаре у глагола **приподнялся**, если считать **на мыски** обстоятельством. Нельзя же **приподняться на стул** (то есть дополнение в функции дополнения не звучит, а вот в функции обстоятельства без проблем).